# mingw64 (win8.1) how to let him see boost libs?

Tags: c++, windows, g++

I've installed at my win8.1 mingw and I would like to compile my program. 
When I use command:

```
g++ -o test test.cpp -lboost_unit_test_framework-mt
```

I got an error:

```
no such file od directory: 
"#include boost/test/unit_test.hpp" // in "<>" ofc.
```

when I use my msVS it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also must use the `-L` and the `-I` option to specify the directories where the boost libraries and headers are located:

```
g++ -I<path_to_headers> -o test test.cpp -L<path_to_library> -lboost_unit_test_framework-mt
```

Note for the headers path that should be the path containing the `boost` directory.

Comment: Well thanks a lot! It worked, but then said: 
D:/programy/mingw-w64/......../bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lboost_unit_test_framework-mt

any idea what to do now?

EDIT:
My command: 
g++ -I C:\biblioteki\boost_1_57_0 -o test test.cpp -L C:\biblioteki\boost_1_57_0\lib64-msvc-12.0 -lboost_unit_test_framework-mt

Comment: You did specify the `-L` option as mentioned? Put the path there where the `libboost_unit_test_framework-mt.lib` file is located.

Comment: I've checked location, and at this direction is lib called a little bit different: libboost_unit_test_framework-vc120-mt-1_57 so I used that command: g++ -I C:\biblioteki\boost_1_57_0\ -o test boostUT.cpp -L C:\biblioteki\boost_1_57_0\lib64-msvc-12.0\ -libboost_unit_test_framework-vc120-mt-1_57

but it also doesn't work. Strange becouse I've copied the name of file and path so it should be fine. Prev. function I had frome some tutorial so i thought it may be old name of lib- that's why I've tried to change that name to the one I can see in that destination.

Comment: With the `-l` option `lib` is automatically prefixed, so you specify `-lboost_unit_test_framework-vc120-mt-1_57`. Also I'm not sure if the files compiled with Visual Studio will work well with MinGW GCC. Usually you use a boost installaiton that was created with the same compiler.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that- thanks for your patience. It works with some problems: http://i61.tinypic.com/20h1vg9.png
So, any idea ;)?

Comment: Looks like the `boost_unit_test_framework-vc120-mt-1_57` needs other libraries from boost. Check their docs and add them accordingly. Or ask another question please.

Comment: ok, so it seems to me, that I will have to wait 90 min ;)
Thanks for your help!